# Flutter Dart - How to make a container with outward borderRadius.circular(20) instead of inward?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

for my Container `borderRadius`. I am currently using `borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))`. I want instead of it taking out the inside I want a border that adds to the outside like a triangluar like shape thing instead of taking away a triangleish looking thing.

Comment: I think an image would help to understand better what you want

Comment: @encubos ok i did

Comment: So just to clarify you want like four triangle attached to the corners of a rectangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this easily using a custom ClipperPath.

Define a custom ClipperPath as given below.

```
  class CustomClipPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final radius = 10.0;
  final arcHeight = 50.0;
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width, size.height - arcHeight),
        radius: Radius.circular(radius));
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - arcHeight / 2);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - arcHeight / 2);
    path.lineTo(0,size.height- arcHeight);
     path.arcToPoint(Offset(0, size.height),
        radius: Radius.circular(radius));

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Then you can apply it to any container like shown below.

```
 ClipPath(
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 200,
            alignment:Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          clipper: CustomClipPath(),
        )
```

[image]

I am sharing a live demo on the Dartpad, find it [here](https://dartpad.dev/65099f260a14766b87e3cf7c438e10b5).